# Library to determine whether a smartphone picture was taken with front or rear camera

Tags: open-source, library, image-processing, camera, exif

I want to detect programmatically whether a picture was taken with:

- a front-facing camera,
- a rear-facing camera,
- or whether we can not tell.

Is there a library for that?

Requirements:

- Works offline.
- Open source.
- It is for an Android app, so bonus for Java, but I can also do the porting so don't hesitate to post solutions in other languages.
- Works with JPG's EXIF, bonus for other formats. Alternatively it could take EXIF properties values as input.
- Reasonably fast, the detection should take less than a second once the image's data is loaded.
- Aiming for around 97% reliability (excluding "*we can not tell*" cases).
- Below 500 kilobytes.

The app is running on the phone that took the picture, solutions that take advantage of this fact are acceptable too.

Context: People usually take very different pictures depending on front/rear, so that would give my app very important hints.

Since EXIF does not seem to have a property for front/back, a solution could embed a database of phone models and guess from the model name and lens resolution as tipped at https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/79179/rear-or-front-facing-camera-through-exif-data , OpenData question about such a database: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13581/focal-length-of-both-front-and-back-cameras-of-popular-smartphones

Comment: "People usually take very different pictures depending on front/rear" - can you explain? Frankly, I do not believe that what you ask can be done (except, perhaps, that large pictures of a single face are probably the front camera (or pics containing an arm/selfie-stick obviously holding the 'phone); or that if all pictures are from the same 'phone then there ought to be only two resolutions, with the larger being the rear camera)

Comment: It can definitely be done. Just have your code take the model name, match it against an embedded database of phones focal lengths for both rear and front, and you are done. There might be smarter algorithms. More context for the curious: https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons/issues/1898

Comment: Know you of such a database ([hint](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/), Failing that, would you be prepared to compile one and maintain it as new 'phones are released? And how are you getting the model name (especially if a pic has no EXIF)?

Comment: Yes, in parallel I am looking for a maintained database, and will ask at OpenData once I am confident about my requirements :-) Pictures with no EXIF are already considered as a separate case by the algorithm, so they are outside of scope.

Comment: Suddenly it becomes much cleaner, and I think that you are really just looking for the database, plus a few lines of Python which you code yourself. I doubt that you will find an app off-the-shelf, but your S.O rep indicates that the coding should be no problem :-)

Comment: I am still open to any other solution, though. In particular, I started thinking that if the Android API gives me the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view of each camera of the device, I *might* be able to figure out which one is the front and which one is the rear, because the front one usually has a larger field of view, *I believe*. Once again, if someone has figured it out already I would prefer to use their solution :-)

Comment: I am still not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you have access to each device which will take the pics? If not, how does the Android API help you? Where do you get the pics from?

Comment: @Mawg, I have access to each device because my app is running on each. The app helps people upload picture they have just taken with their phone.

Comment: Some cameras do save it `"exiftool IMG_20180913_200444.jpg | grep -i "Lens Facing"` RESULT:  `Lens Facing                     : Back`  shot with (`Camera Model Name               : ONEPLUS A6003`)